# How to calculate the counts of each distinct value of all the columns in a pyspark dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How to calculate the counts of each distinct value in column for all the columns in a pyspark dataframe?
This is my input dataframe:

```
spark.table("table1").show()
+-------+---------+------- +--------+
|col1   | col2    | col3   | col4   |
+-------+---------+------- +--------+
|aa     |   ss    |  sss   |  jjj   |
|bb     |   123   |  1203  |  uuu   |
|null   |   123   |  null  |  zzz   |
|null   |   123   |  1203  |  6543  |
+-------+---------+--------+--------+
```

I need the final output data frame some thing like this:

```
+-----------+-------------+-------+-------+------------+
|table_name | Column_name | Value | count | percentage |
+-----------+-------------+-------+-------+------------+
|table1     |   col1      |  aa   |  1    |            |
|table1     |   col1      |  bb   |  1    |            |
|table1     |   col1      |  null |  2    |            |
|table1     |   col2      |  ss   |  1    |            |
|table1     |   col2      |  123  |  3    |            |
|table1     |   col3      |  sss  |  1    |            |
|table1     |   col3      |  1203 |  2    |            |
|table1     |   col3      |  null |  1    |            |
|table1     |   col4      |  jjj  |  1    |            |
|table1     |   col4      |  uuu  |  1    |            |
|table1     |   col4      |  zzz  |  1    |            |
|table1     |   col4      |  6543 |  1    |            |
+-----------+-------------+-------+-------+------------+
```

I have Python logic for calculating the percentage. Same needs to be implemented in Pyspark

```
percentages.append(excel['enum'][col].value_counts()[value]/excel['enum'][col].shape[0] * 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by each column to count different values then union all the intermediary dataframes. Or use counting over window partitioned by each column then unpivot to get the desired output. Here's an example:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df = spark.createDataFrame([
   ("aa", "ss", "sss", "jjj"), ("bb", "123", "1203", "uuu"),
   (None, "123", None, "zzz"), (None, "123", "1203", "6543")
], ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"])

result = df.select(*[
   F.struct(
       F.col(c).alias("Value"),
       F.count(F.coalesce(F.col(c), F.lit("null"))).over(Window.partitionBy(c)).alias("count")
   ).alias(c) for c in df.columns
]).agg(*[
   F.collect_set(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns
]).selectExpr(
   f"stack({len(df.columns)}," + ','.join(chain(*[(c, f"'{c}'") for c in df.columns])) + ")"
).selectExpr(
   "col1 as Column_name", "inline(col0)"
).withColumn(
   "percentage",
   F.round(F.col("count") / df.count() * 100, 2)
)

result.show()
# +-----------+-----+-----+----------+
# |Column_name|Value|count|percentage|
# +-----------+-----+-----+----------+
# |col1       |null |2    |50.0      |
# |col1       |bb   |1    |25.0      |
# |col1       |aa   |1    |25.0      |
# |col2       |123  |3    |75.0      |
# |col2       |ss   |1    |25.0      |
# |col3       |null |1    |25.0      |
# |col3       |1203 |2    |50.0      |
# |col3       |sss  |1    |25.0      |
# |col4       |jjj  |1    |25.0      |
# |col4       |uuu  |1    |25.0      |
# |col4       |zzz  |1    |25.0      |
# |col4       |6543 |1    |25.0      |
# +-----------+-----+-----+----------+
```

Comment: Hi when I mention few columns as part of the dataframe it is working.. But when I try to take all columns it OS throwing error

Comment: Column length exceeded kind of Error

Comment: The same logic implemented in my data frame which is having around 100 columns and getting error. Need help on this thanks in advance…

Comment: Hi the above solution works fine for small volumes and its taking longer time and sometimes getting failed for large data. can you please suggest a solution.